# PostgreSQL: return all rows including duplicates

Tags: postgresql, web, duplicates

Some background: my client is requesting a way to find out who is using his computers.  Each computer user has a unique barcode attached to their account which ends up in a log file (recording date and time among other things), but the log file he looks at does not report the residence for these users which he needs.  I have a separate read-only PostgreSQL database that I can search against to find the residence of the user using their barcode.  I setup a web form using a textarea field to allow the client to input a list of barcodes.  I then capture the entire string into a variable and put together a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT

n.last_name as name,
p.barcode as barcode, 
p.home as residence 

FROM db.pt_view p JOIN db.pt_record_fullname n ON p.id = n.patron_record_id 

WHERE p.barcode IN ('25260045344400','25233423433332','25233423433332','...)
```

This works, but the "IN" operator of course removes all of the duplicate barcodes.  I need all of the barcodes (duplicate or not) to match up to the number of entries in the log file.  A barcode can appear many times in the log at different dates and times. Using this query above, I entered in 918 barcodes and only returned 450.

I'm a relative PostgreSQL and database noob, so I'm sure there's a better way to handle this and return all of the records (with duplicates).  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `IN` isn't doing what you want, perhaps the on-the-fly capabilities of `VALUES` as a subquery will do.

```
SELECT
n.last_name as name, /* don't recommend using reserved word name this way */
p.barcode as barcode, 
p.home as residence 

FROM db.pt_view p
JOIN db.pt_record_fullname n ON p.id = n.patron_record_id 
JOIN (VALUES('25260045344400'),('25233423433332'),('25233423433332') /* , ...*/))
         AS codes(barcode)
     ON p.barcode=codes.barcode;
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  This did work, but only returned the first record for 25260045344400.  Is there anything else I can try?  Thank you!

Comment: I only see 25260045344400 once in the list, so I would only expect it once in the output. Are there multiple entries per barcode in the pt_view table or only in the list of values? I would think the latter.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The results for barcode 25260045344400 were the only row returned, even though I had added a value for 25233423433332 as well.  If it makes this easier I can try to use sqlfiddle and get some sample data to look at.  Thanks again.

Comment: This surprises me. I would guess a typo.

Comment: I figured it out.  We just needed to put parentheses around each barcode like this:

`JOIN (VALUES('25241000335670'),('25241000335670'),('25240001919441')) AS codes(code) ON p.barcode = codes.code;`  Thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks for fixing that up. I had one row of many columns, let me fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try cartesian product

if you use JOIN without ON,will create a cartesian product,this is a product  ALL x ALL rows and use a condicional to end.

somethink like:

```
SELECT

n.last_name as name,
p.barcode as barcode, 
p.home as residence 

FROM db.pt_view p JOIN db.pt_record_fullname n 

WHERE p.barcode IN ('25260045344400','25233423433332','25233423433332','...) and p.id = n.patron_record_id
```

PD: my english is not good xD

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately this didn't work for me.  It's expecting an **ON** as part of the query.